# I want to genrate dynamic variable in TWIG and fetch value

Tags: twig

i want to set dynamic variable and get value of that variable. I had pass "orderDetails" to my twig template.

```
    $customerProfile = array(
      'ns1' => $customerProfile->getNs1(),
      'ns2' => $customerProfile->getNs2(),
      'custId' => $customerProfile->getCustId()
)

return $this->render('PortalBundle::popup.html.twig', array(
            'orderDetails' => $customerProfile
        ));
```

get that variable like {{orderDetails.ns1}}, {{orderDetails.ns2}} like this but i have 15 to 16 variable like this and i want to fetch this variable in loop.

i have code for this like

```
{% for i in 1..13 %}
     {% set nsOrd = 'orderDetails.ns'~i %}
          {% if nsOrd %}
                {{nsOrd}}
          {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

i want to fetch variable {{orderDetails.ns1}} and other. Give me your suggestion.

Comment: If `orderDetails` is an array, just use `for...in`, no need to generate the indexes. E.g. `{% for nsOrd in orderDetails %}`.

Comment: `$customerProfile = array(
      'ns1' => $customerProfile->getNs1(),
      'ns2' => $customerProfile->getNs2(),
)

return $this->render('PortalBundle::popup.html.twig', array(
            'orderDetails' => $customerProfile
        ));`

Comment: How i fetch only ns1 and ns2?

Comment: I see. Well, you could simply do `{% for x in ['ns1', 'ns2] %}` and so on. But honestly, I think you're overworking the view. Simply create a good, usable data-struture in the controller, and pass that to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Yoshi, I have hundered of variable in array. thanks for support, i have found and successfully get output using this.

```
{% for i in 1..13 %}
     {% if orderDetails['ns' ~ i] is defined %}
           {{orderDetails['ns' ~ i]}}
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```